# changing this colour from white to black using css and or html

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to change this colour from white to what ever colour suits me.

TIA :)

[here is a screen shot of my website on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiCv4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in you < head > :

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

This will change to black-translucent, but feel free to change it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on my site:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#f08b21" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).